# How do i configure Activiti 5.14 to work as per 'Activiti In Action'?

Tags: activiti

I have downloaded Activiti 5.14 and H2 database. Ran the 'Create' script for the H2 Activiti database. Changed the Connection URL to point to the local database in the Tomcat/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/classes/db.properties. Now Eclipse test DOES connect to the database, since earlier it was not sensing the table ACT_GE_PROPERTY.

When i ran "BookOrderTest.java" from the book, i got mismatch of 5.9 and 5.14 so i changed schema_version to 5.9 in the ACT_GE_PROPERTY table of "H2" database. Now i get  error

```
'Activiti database problem: no historyLevel property specified'.
```

I took tips from [Similar query in forum](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=151893) and  [Blog by author](http://bpmn20inaction.blogspot.in/2013/02/activiti-in-action-updates-part-1.html)

How can i setup my system to run along with the book ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that the source code of the book is under development.

https://code.google.com/p/activitiinaction/

The code is upgraded to version 5.12 or 5.13 of Activiti. I'll make sure it gets upgraded to 5.14 soon. So you can update to the latest book code from this Google code repository.

For now you have two options, either work with an older version of Activiti or change the Activiti version in the pom.xml file of the book source code.

Best regards,

Tijs

Comment: The svn checkout doesn't work for me, so i am reworking changes as per 'diff' from rev 320 upwards.Hope it works out in the end.Thanks.